# How to initialize the array fields of a struct with zeroes

Tags: c, struct

I have a the following struct

```
typedef struct mainstruct {
    uint32_t        var1;
    field_struct    var2[2];
    uint32_t        var3;
} main_struct;
```

where field_struct is :

```
typedef struct fieldstruct {
    uint8_t     var11[8];
    uint32_t    var22; 
    uint32_t    var33; 
    uint8_t     var44[16];
    uint8_t     var55[16];
    uint8_t     var66[16];
} field_struct;
```

How can I initialize all the field_struct field in main_struct to all zeroes ?
Also var1 and var2 need to be initialized to specific values.

Comment: If you have a declaration with an initializer, e.g. `main_struct ms = { .var1 = 1 };`, then all unspecified fields will be initialized to zero.

Comment: @Lundin: fixed it in the meantime, thanks

Comment: `main_struct ms = {42u, {{0}}, 7u};`

Comment: ```main_struct *m; memset(m->field_struct, 0, 2 * sizeof(field_struct));```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you partially initialize the struct, the rest of the members that you don't initialize explicitly are set to zero. So it is enough to just initialize those members that need specific values:

```
main_struct ms = 
{
  .var1 = something,
  .var2 = { something_else },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I initialize all the `field_struct` field in `main_struct` to all zeroes?

If you don't have access to designated initializers (C99 and C11), you can simply zero-initialize the entire struct and then initialize the rest to whatever you need:

```
main_struct s = {0};
s.var1 = ...;
```

The optimizer will do the right thing. Of course, if you don't want to initialize everything, you would have to manually initialize the ones you need only.

Comment: Because of a special case in the language to make initialization of scalars consistent, and the generously flexible rules for nested braces in initializers, `= {0}` can be used to correctly initialize any type in the language to its appropriate zero value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set default values for struct members then you simply can't do it: structures are data types, not instances of data types.

Instead, if you only want to initialize the members of an instance of your data type then you can use the method described in [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55843498/5296106).